# Inserción de datos en formulario con datos NULL

Tags: php, html, php5

Tengo un problema con un formulario, en si la `función es una bitácora de equipos a préstamo`, `por lo cual necesito enviar un formulario con campos null (ya están establecidos en mi BD)` Así como también algunos campos los inserto llaves foráneas. **Mi formulario si inserta en la base de datos** si lleno todos los campos dentro de mi formulario pero `si dejo los campos vacíos para que se llenen después (recepción de equipos) no me inserta nada de lo datos.`

Asi esta creada mi tabla "prestamo"

```
id_prestamo     PK
fecha1  
hora1   
descripcion
id_usuario        FK
id_departamento   FK
id_entrega        FK
fecha2                NULL
hora2                 NULL
id_ingeniero      FK  NULL
id_recepcion      FK  NULL
```

```html
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");
 
 
 if (isset($_POST['fecha1']) && !empty($_POST['fecha1']) &&
    (isset($_POST['hora1']) && !empty($_POST['hora1'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['descripcion']) && !empty($_POST['descripcion'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['id_usuario']) && !empty($_POST['id_usuario'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['id_departamento']) && !empty($_POST['id_departamento'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['id_entrega']) && !empty($_POST['id_entrega'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['fecha2']) && !empty($_POST['fecha2'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['hora2']) && !empty($_POST['hora2'])) &&
 (isset($_POST['id_ingeniero']) && !empty($_POST['id_ingeniero'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_recepcion']) && !empty($_POST['id_recepcion']))){
  
  
    $Prestamo1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
 $Prestamo2 = $_POST['hora1'];
 $Prestamo3 = $_POST['descripcion'];
 $Prestamo4 = $_POST['id_usuario'];
 $Prestamo5 = $_POST['id_departamento'];
 $Prestamo6 = $_POST['id_entrega'];
 $Prestamo7 = $_POST['fecha2'];
 $Prestamo8 = $_POST['hora2'];
 $Prestamo9 = $_POST['id_ingeniero'];
 $Prestamo10 = $_POST['id_recepcion'];
 

 
 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamo (fecha1, hora1, descripcion, id_usuario, id_departamento, id_entrega, fecha2, hora2,  id_ingeniero, id_recepcion) values ('$Prestamo1','$Prestamo2', '$Prestamo3', '$Prestamo4', '$Prestamo5', '$Prestamo6', '$Prestamo7', '$Prestamo8', '$Prestamo9', '$Prestamo10')")) {
        
 $Prestamo1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
 $Prestamo2 = $_POST['hora1'];
 $Prestamo3 = $_POST['descripcion'];
 $Prestamo4 = $_POST['id_usuario'];
 $Prestamo5 = $_POST['id_departamento'];
 $Prestamo6 = $_POST['id_entrega'];
 $Prestamo7 = $_POST['fecha2'];
 $Prestamo8 = $_POST['hora2'];
 $Prestamo7 = $_POST['id_ingeniero'];
 $Prestamo8 = $_POST['id_recepcion'];
 
 
  
         if($stmt->execute())
  {  
    echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
  }
     else
     {
      '<script>alert("Error al ingresar")</script> ';
    }
    
        }
}
?>

<html>

<head>

<form action="" method=post name="formulario">


<style>
div label
{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 
}


</style>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- FooTable Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="js/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/demo-rows.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
   <div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
    Sistema Integral de Inventarios
   </div><br/><br/><br/><br/>
   
           
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Consulta de Registros</strong>
   <a href="prestamo_edit.php" ><img src="images/file_get.png"  width="50" height="50" title="consultar" style="cursor:pointer"></a></p>

<title>Gesti&oacuten de Inventarios</title>



<body>





<center><fieldset style="width:40%" "width:900px">

<td>


    <legend >Registro de Equipo a Prestamo</legend><br />
 
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="guardar.php" autocomplete="off">


 <h5 >Entrega</h5>



                    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fecha1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicio:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha1" name="fecha1"  placeholder="Ingresa la Fecha">
          </div>
              </div><br /><br />
        
     
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="hora1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Inicio:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora1" name="hora1"  placeholder="Ingresa la Hora">
          </div>
              </div><br /><br /> 
        
        
        
     
        
        
        
        
        
        
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario:</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_usuario, nombre FROM usuarios";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuario]\">$row[nombre] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_usuario" name="id_usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Usuario</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select></div></div><br /><br /> 




                  <div class="form-group">
          <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripcion:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion"  placeholder="Ingresa la Descripcion">
          </div>
              </div><br /><br />









<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_departamento" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Departamento:</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_departamento, descripcion FROM departamento";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_departamento]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_departamento" name="id_departamento" placeholder="Departamento">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Departamento</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select></div></div><br /><br /> 






<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_entrega" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estatus Entrega:</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_entrega, descripcion FROM entrega";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_entrega]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_entrega" name="id_entrega" placeholder="Entrega">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Estatus de Entrega</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select></div></div><br /><br />




 <h5 >Recepción</h5>








                     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fecha2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Fin:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha2" name="fecha2"  placeholder="Ingresa la Fecha">
          </div>
              </div><br /><br />
        
     
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="hora2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Fin:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora2" name="hora2"  placeholder="Ingresa la Hora">
          </div>
              </div><br /><br /> 








<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_ingeniero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ingeniero:</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_ingeniero, descripcion FROM ingeniero";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_ingeniero]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_ingeniero" name="id_ingeniero" placeholder="Ingeniero">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Ingeniero</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select></div></div><br /><br />






<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_recepcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estatus Recepción:</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_recepcion, descripcion FROM recepcion";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_recepcion]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_recepcion" name="id_recepcion" placeholder="Recepción">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Estatus de Entrega</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select></div></div><br /><br />
        
        
        
        
        
 <p align="center"><br /><input type="submit"  name="botonGuardar"class="bg-primary" value="Agregar"  /></p>
 
 
 
</td><center></fieldset><br></br>





</form>



<?php
     include("includes/menus.php"); ?>
     </div>
     <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!--<script src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <!-- Add in any FooTable dependencies we may need -->
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Add in FooTable itself -->
  <script src="js/compiled/footable.js"></script>
  <!-- Initialize FooTable -->
  <script>
   jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
   });
  </script>

  </body>

   

    </html>
```

Comment: Me parece obvio que no inserte si tienes todos los campos chequeados con `isset`

Answer (score 0):

Solamente debes de chequear por la existencia de los campos que son requeridos por tu base de datos.  Para los que no son requeridos, puedes substituirlos for `NULL` si no estan presentes.  Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");


 if (isset($_POST['fecha1']) && !empty($_POST['fecha1']) &&
    (isset($_POST['hora1']) && !empty($_POST['hora1'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['descripcion']) && !empty($_POST['descripcion'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_usuario']) && !empty($_POST['id_usuario'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_departamento']) && !empty($_POST['id_departamento'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['id_entrega']) && !empty($_POST['id_entrega']))) {            

    $Prestamo1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
    $Prestamo2 = $_POST['hora1'];
    $Prestamo3 = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $Prestamo4 = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $Prestamo5 = $_POST['id_departamento'];
    $Prestamo6 = $_POST['id_entrega'];
    $Prestamo7 = (isset($_POST['fecha2']) && !empty($_POST['fecha2'])) ? $_POST['fecha2'] : NULL;
    $Prestamo8 = (isset($_POST['hora2']) && !empty($_POST['hora2'])) ?  $_POST['hora2'] : NULL;
    $Prestamo9 = (isset($_POST['id_ingeniero']) && !empty($_POST['id_ingeniero'])) ? $_POST['id_ingeniero'] : NULL;
    $Prestamo10 = (isset($_POST['id_recepcion']) && !empty($_POST['id_recepcion'])) ? $_POST['id_recepcion'] : NULL;

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamo (fecha1, hora1, descripcion, id_usuario, id_departamento, id_entrega, fecha2, hora2,  id_ingeniero, id_recepcion) values ('$Prestamo1','$Prestamo2', '$Prestamo3', '$Prestamo4', '$Prestamo5', '$Prestamo6', '$Prestamo7', '$Prestamo8', '$Prestamo9', '$Prestamo10')")) {

         if($stmt->execute()) {     
             echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
         } else {
                     '<script>alert("Error al ingresar")</script> ';
         }

    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por contestar, pero mi pregunta es no tengo que definir tambien mis variables al inicio? ya que colocando el codigo que me proporcionaste no me inserta aun nada.... Saludos

Comment: Intenta poner los `NULL` entre comillas.

Comment: imprimí lo que hay en mi variable $stmt  colocando y quitando las comillas como me indicas y me sale el siguiente error  mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 0 [field_count] => 0 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )

Comment: El código original tiene más errores, por ejemplo, él usa `prepare`, pero luego no pasa las variables debidamente usando `bind_param`. Esto es al menos un grave error de seguridad y puede que también lo sea a nivel de código. También, para escribir un código menos confuso con tantos `isset` y `empty`, ten en cuenta que **`empty` es suficiente**, sirve para evaluar ambas cosas. O sea cuando tú pones algo como esto: `$Prestamo7 = empty($_POST['fecha2']) ? NULL : $_POST['fecha2'];` tanto si la clave `fecha2` no ha sido posteada, como si está vacía, te asignará `NULL` al valor de la variable.